Immutability across programming languages
I'm quite confused about the concept of mutability (or mutation?), especially across different languages. In a language like Python:
x = 10 
x = 20

I believe this is called shadowing (or rebinding) and not mutability, because the literal 10 will evaluate to an integer object that is immutable.
In some languages like Racket, if I write (define x 10), I can no longer change it. Isn't that a form of immutability?
In the C++ case, I hear people say that this is an example of mutability:
int x = 10;
x = 20;

and that if I want to enforce immutability, I have to use const int x = 10;
That got me quite confused. Would you please clarify this for me? Also, is there a difference between the concept of mutability in functional languages and non-functional languages, and do purely functional languages have something to do with this?

If it helps. Python's x = 10 is more like int *x; (*x) = 10in C++. x is just a name for an object, not the chunk of memory containing the object itself.

This is a common confusion with immutability. There's a difference between an immutable value and an immutable reference.
For example, say you have x = 10. You can't do something like 10 = 20 to change the value of x. The 10 is immutable. You can do x = 20, unless x is declared to be immutable. But that doesn't change the value of 10, just the value of x.
On the other hand, you can have const x = SomeObject(), where you can change stuff inside SomeObject, but you can't reassign x to point to a different object.
Values of value types (like numbers and strings in most languages) are immutable, but variables aren't unless declared to be such, even variables pointing to immutable values.

I agree with the distinction but I think the conclusion misses the mark on its phrasing. Immutability of variables is a relevant consideration when dealing with value types (and indeed very different from an object being immutable or not). However, I find "primitives like numbers and strings are immutable" a bit of a nonsensical point to bring up. Types (which is what you're referring to with "primitives") have no concept of mutability. Mutation happens on state, which means that you need to be thinking of (reference and value type) variables and (reference type) objects.

That aside, still a +1 from me on pointing out the distinction between variable and object mutability.

@BartVanIngenSchenau "I think "literal" was the word you were looking for for things like 10 or "Hello"" - no, the term "literal" refers to an expression in source code, whereas the sentence needs to refer to values.

@Flater I don't think there's a problem with "primitives like numbers and strings", it means "primitive values like number and string values"

@Bergi In the context of code and syntax a literal refers to an explicit value. Bart is correct. Karl's mention of 10=20 is specifically using literals, not value-type variables of any kind.

@Bergi: Whether they're primitives is irrelevant, the only thing that matters is that they're a value type. Not a value, a value type. Those are two distinct concepts. A reference is in and of itself a value as well. It is the type's nature (i.e. reference type or value type) that provides the distinction between the behaviors, not the value itself that is being assigned.

@Flater Ah, yes, "value type" is more accurate than "primitive type", I conflated the two because in most languages they are the same set of types (but one could imagine a mutable primitive "semaphore" type or something). However I still disagree with the term "literal", which does not refer to a value but rather the notation for a value in code. And while many literals produce immutable values when evaluated, not all of them do, like {} in JS or "str" in C.

Way, way back in Fortran 4 there was a way to change 10 to 20 using "Blank Common." The problem was that the literal 10 was stored as a reference to a value in common.

Many languages have literal syntax for mutable objects, such as lists and dictionaries. "Primitive" is the more correct word here, and the edit should not have been made. "Literal" is a purely syntactic category; literals are tokens in the source code, not values which exist at runtime, so it doesn't strictly make sense to say that a literal itself is immutable or mutable.

@Bergi: I get the feeling you're getting caught up on the distinction between what Karl was trying to say and what you believe would have been better to say. I'm with Bart that Karl intended to refer to literals. I also don't fully agree with Karl's point (as per my first comment here) but he was referring to literals (on the implicit notion that all literals are value types, which I agree with you is not entirely correct due to some edge cases).

@Flater No, I was trying to say what Kaya3 has expressed much better now. A literal is a type of expression in the language grammar, not a runtime value.

Thank you for your answer.
I didn't understand something when you said, "You can't do something like 10 = 20 to change the value of x. The 10 is immutable." The expression 10 = 20 didn't make sense to me. Why would we consider if it changes the value of x if it doesn't have anything to do with x? (at least from what I understand)

@Ghassen Consider "similar" code like x = y then y.foo = 20, where the second statement changes the value of x even though it does not mention x.

Welcome to one of the fun quirks of programming in different languages (and their different semantics)
In a general sense, whether something has the property of mutability, or if there is simply rebinding going on is one of perspective.
using a modified example like this:
a = new list(0, 1)
b = new list(1, 2, 3)
x=a
x=b

After this code runs, you would expect if you examined x for it to be a list of the values 1, 2 and 3.  This is an example of x being mutable.
If you looked at the value of a you would see it still contained a list of the values 0 and 1.  This might imply that the implementation of mutability of the variable x was done by rebinding its value to reference the variable b.
Now imagine if we then added the line
x.add(7)

now if we look at the value of x we know it will contain a list of 1,2,3 and 7  However what will be the value in b ??
If x was mutated by being assigned a copy of b then b will only contain 1,2 and 3
If x was mutated by being rebound to b then b will contain 1,2,3 and 7
Most programmers will refer to being rebound as "copying by reference", and this is the only option in most programming languages.  However, some languages also enable copy by value.  In which case a new list object was created and the list of items was copied into the new list.  C++ is a language where copy by value is implemented, and is the default - you include a reference modifier to a variable declaration to mean that the variable contains references (bindings) to other objects.
Functional languages are typically immutable. It is this immutability that makes them functional, and that makes not only repeated variable assignments impossible, but also prevents code like this:
a = new list(1, 2, 3)
foreach (x in a)
  print(x)

The value of x is no longer immutable, and functional programming does not allow this.

This is also a valid answer although it does not address the c++ part of the question. The key to the mutability question is indeed the change of the object to which x refers ("binding") rather than the changing x to refer to another object leaving the forst one intact. I do not understand why people downvoted here +1

In general, the mutability says that the values of object can be changed. Your C++ example is indeed mutability, because x is an int object, that the value 10 is stored in the object and that the assignment operator will OVERWRITE the old value to set it to 20.
C++ has by default a value semantic: objects are copied by value by default, unless you define another semantic or decide knowingly to work with pointers or references. Other languages such as Java are primarily reference based. When you copy an object, you duplicate in reality a reference and two variables then allow to change the same object. In this context, mutability is life critical, to not accidentally alter an object owned by someone else. The whole class is made immutable.
In C++ immutability can be controlled at the object level. const allows to qualify any object of any type to be immutable:
const int x=10;  
const Person p("Graddy","Booch");

The objects x and p can then no longer be changed. The concept of immutability is of surgical precision in C++, as you can also define member functions (methods) that are guaranteed to leave the object unchanged:
class MyTemperature {
public:
   MyTemperature(int t):temp(t){}
   int get() const;
   void set(int t); // can't be used on a const object
private:
   int temp;
};

Last but not least, one could imagine having some internal temporary fields that could change despite an object is const because they are not really relevant for the object state (e.g. like a ca he or memoization that could be rebuilt whenever needed). These members can be labelled as mutable.
The concept is similar to immutability in functional language although not the same. Functional languages avoid side effects. So if you'd have variables like in Java or C++, and the object would be mutable, you would have plenty of side effects. So you'll have to have immutable objects passed as parameters or returned by the functions.

It is a little bit confusing when you include primitive types of C++ like int in your phrasing of an "object" - that's quite unusual and has potential to confuse readers. I see the same problem in your phrasing about Java - Java makes a clear distinction between primitive value types (which are not reference based), and reference types - which obviously are.

@DocBrown Java makes indeed a clear distinction between primitive value types and others. But it is primarily reference based for any class that you'll define. C++ does not have such a distinction: an int is by definition of the c++ standard and object, even if int is not defined as a class. I used it only because OP used it in his/her example.

Ok, I informed myself about the wording in the C++ standard, and I agree, they call int values "objects" (but probably not in the same sense as "OOP objects"). Still I think that phrasing is quite unusual, and I see some potential here to improve your answer.

@Christophe: Not only does C++ make a clear distinction, it even has metaprogramming functions to check that for a given type T. E.g. std::is_class<T> vs std::is_fundamental<T> (There are types which are neither, e.g. pointers to classes)

@DocBrown: Values in C++ are very much not objects. 4 does not have a lifetime, objects do. From a C++ perspective, most of the interesting OO behavior is associated with types, not objects. A (class) type can be polymorphic.

@MSalters: tell Christoph (or the writers of the C++ standard), I know that.

@DocBrown: Your link goes to int variables, not int values. Yet your comment here talks about int values. Since the whole question hinges on variable mutability versus value mutability, the difference is crucial. 4 += 2 is invalid, int x = 4; x+= 2 is valid.

@MSalters: ok, I should have written *they call int variables "objects" * in my comment above, cannot change this glitch anymore. Still: why do you tell me? I way not the one who wrote this answer. When I got you right, you agree to me that Christophe should work on the phrasing of this answer a little bit. Or did I misunderstand you?

@MSalters please read [intro.objects] as I do not see anything therein that would exclude an int from being an object, on contrary. It even gives examples of objects of built-in types.

@DocBrown see above

Furthermore in [basic.types.general].8 : an object ype is a type that is not a function type, not a reference type and not cv void. Later there is a distinction between funamental types and compund types, but none of it is at all relevant for the question of OP, which is a cross language question on immutability.  And here, whether I write tha x holds the value 10 or not, the assignment will ocerwrite this value, i.e the object designated by x is changed, i.e. mutated. So we have here a lot of comments, none of them affecting the validity of the answer

@Christophe: I emphasized int values to stress what is not an object. In int x = 4; the x variable is an object. But the value 4 isn't. You can take the address of an object, you can't take the address of 4.

@DocBrown: The C spec also uses the word "object" in this way. I'm betting that the word "object" has been used this way since before object-oriented programming was ubiquitous enough to drive out other uses.

@DocBrown "Object" in C and in many places in C++ is used for an item that can be modified on its own. For example, integer types are usually "objects". I think bit fields are not objects - one or more bit fields belong to an object, for example 32 single bit bit fields could form a 32 bit object.

@gnasher729 exactly. And bitfields are also objects. It's just that they are not guaranteed to have a unique address unlike other objects. It's indicated in the standard near one of the references I've quoted above ;-)

@ruakh That's correct. The term "object" comes from C, where it refers to any "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values". So not a function (which doesn't take a value), not a #defined constant (which doesn't live in memory). Might be a few other things that don't fall under the aegis of "object", but those are the ones that spring to mind. Most commonly used to distinguish object pointers and function pointers: void* can't point to a function.  It has nothing at all to do with object-oriented programming.

I'd start with C and C++, where things are reasonably simple. You have "objects" in memory, not in the sense of object oriented programming, but items that can be read or changed. These "objects" can be "const", which means an attempt to modify them invokes undefined behaviour. Often the compiler will not allow you to modify a const object, but there are ways around that. Typically behaviours when you try to modify a const object are:
Your application crashes
Your application doesn't store the value
Your application gets into a schizophrenic state whether the object is modified or not
The object is modified

And most common: You don't notice anything wrong in development, but as soon as you deliver your software to a customer, it will fail in the worst possible way.
Apart from objects being constant, pointers to objects may allow modification or not. There are rules for this that are usually sensible, but this being C or C++ you can override them.
int i = 10;
const int* p = &i;
int* q = (int*) p; 

The object i is not constant, but you are not allowed to modify it through the pointer p. You are allowed to modify it through q though. Now take the example
const int i = 10;
const int* p = &i;
int* q = (int*) p; 

i is not modifiable. The compiler won't let you change i through the pointer p. The compiler will let you attempt to change i through the pointer q, but will produce undefined behaviour.
If you have a class or struct that is const, then normally all members are const. There are two exceptions: When you run a C++ constructor, the object members can be modified until the constructor has finished (const instances of class would be quite useless otherwise). There is another exception: If a member is "mutable" then it can be modified and is not const even when it is part of a const object. This is useful for caches, for example. Consider a string class with 0-terminated strings and a function that returns the length. To determine the length, you need to go through all the elements until you find the trailing 0 which is expensive, so you would like to store the length. You can do that by storing the length in a mutable member. So calling the len(function) changes the object, but doesn't logically change it.
In C and C++, classes and structs are not const; it is the individual instances that are const or not. const pointer members mean that the pointer value cannot be changed, but if the pointer points to modifiable data then the data it points to can be changed. This means that you may be able for example to change the title of a const button, which may come very unexpected. So you need to distinguish between "logically unmodifiable" and "physically unmodifiable".
Another unexpected thing: You can have a modifiable object, and both a const and a non-const pointer to it. If I pass a const int * p to a function, the developer may assume that *p cannot change. But if I have an int *q pointing to the same variable then it can change. And a compiler can usually create better code if it knows that an object cannot change - which it often can’t.

x = 10  
x = 20

This is not shadowing.
This is shadowing:
x = 0

def outer():
    x = 1

    def inner():
        x = 2
        print("inner:", x)

    inner()
    print("outer:", x)

outer()
print("global:", x)

# prints
# inner: 2
# outer: 1
# global: 0

Each x belongs to a different scope. So they lead completely different lives. You just can't use them all at the same time because they get in each others way. Ya know, casting shadows on each other.
x = 10  
x = 20

Same scope, same x. With this code that 10 is gone. You ain't getting it back. The question is, why?


Rebinding is a change to the referencing identifier.
Assignment is a change to (the referenced) variable.
Mutation is a change to an object in memory, possibly referenced by a variable or bound to an identifier.


It depends on how your language implements that code.

Rebinding -> The 10 is lost. It exists somewhere but we forgot where. But we know where this nifty 20 is.

Assignment -> The 10 is dead. It now looks like a 20.

Mutation -> Can happen to values and to references. Which happened here depends on your language.



The dangers of mutation specifically apply to alias mutation; a lot of times when people claim "immutability", what they really claim (or want) is alias immutability.

An alias is a value that is referenced by multiple variables. For example in C:
int x = 4;
int* y = &x;

x and y are aliases of each other. If one of them is mutated, the other changes.
x = 5;
printf("%d", *y); // prints 5
*y = 3
printf("%d", x); // prints 3

The problem with alias mutation is that it's hard (sometimes literally impossible) to know whether a variable's alias was mutated. For example:
int* y;

int main() {
  int x = 4;
  y = &x;
  f();
  printf("%d", x);
  return 0;
}

What will this print? To know the answer, we need to know the body of f, because it could re-assign *y. Moreover, if f is:
void f() {
    g();
    h();
    i();
}

Now we need to know the body of g, h, i...

Alias mutation has real-world consequences. Every day, a developer has a variable that they assume isn't going to mutate, but it was aliased somewhere, and some function mutates that alias, so it mutates the variable. The developer can't keep track of every alias of every variable, so they can't know at a glance "is this call to f going to change x" for some fs and xs; they assume, and when these assumptions turn out to be wrong, it's a pain to debug.
But mutation without aliases doesn't have this issue. If the only way x can be mutated is through a statement x =, a developer can be certain that it remains constant throughout some lines, by checking that none of the lines contain x =. In fact, even if the language has a "mutable borrow" that temporarily lets other functions mutate a value, e.g. f(&mut x) lets that particular call to f mutate x, a developer can still be certain that x remains constant throughout every line that doesn't contain an assignment or mutable borrow of x.

And this basically the generic pitch for Rust, a language that permits mutability but exclusively forbids alias mutability (except for explicitly-allowed "interior mutability"). But even outside of Rust, understanding the unique danger of alias mutation is useful. For example, if you're careful not to leak variables, i.e. assign them globally or pass them to functions except behind "read-only" wrappers, you can be certain that they aren't mutated within a particular code region even in C++ and Java.

“x and y…” I think the website has removed an asterisk.

Immutability is not a very fundamental notion in programming; what it means (if anything) is highly dependent on details of programming language semantics, such as argument passing conventions. Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a mutable value: whenever one changes something, it is not the values (in the mathematical sense) themselves that change, just the question which values are contained in storage.
What is visible to the programmer is the association of expressions (including mere identifiers) to their values. In purely functional programming languages, that association once it exists can never be modified (the same expression in the same context will always continue to refer to the same value) so mutability is not a thing there. In other languages, there is usually at least the assignment of a new value to a variable that can change this association. The fact that this is possible for variables of a given type does not make the type mutable; what makes a type mutable is when the value of a variable of this type can change by something else than assignment to the variable, presumably by manipulation of the memory accessed by that variable. This applies almost exclusively to large, composite, types like arrays, strings or classes: if an integer variable resides in a register then there is no way to alter its value other than by assignment to the variable.
Often higher level languages will have an implicit pointer/reference level between the location of the variable and the value stored, in particular if the type allows values requiring vastly different amounts of storage (like unrestricted strings). Then typically assignment to the variable will be implemented by making it refer to a different memory region rather than modifying the values stored in the original memory region. Also often passing the value to a different variable (as happens in argument passing) is often implemented by just copying the reference, so original and copy are aliases for the same storage. If the language provides in addition operations that do transform the value in-place, then such operations applied to an alias will also be visible through the original variable, which then has mutable behaviour. However, if no such in-place operations are provided, then it can be ensured that in the absence of direct assignments (and of memory corruption, or cosmic rays), the value will continue to access the same value; in this case the type can be said to be immutable. This property is important in some cases, as in Python dictionaries: the integrity of the dictionary depends on the fact that no unexpected changes can occur to the key-part of its key-value pairs, so it insists that key are of an immutable type.
In C++, the user has control over everything (and the responsibility to not abuse this power), so immutability is not an issue as such. One can declare a type to be a reference or pointer to constant, which means one is protected against altering the corresponding memory contents through this reference/pointer, but if some part of the program already had non-const access to the memory, that part can still modify the memory contents, so there is no guarantee of immutability here. Classes can make it impossible for decent clients (those who refrain from const-casting and out-of-bounds writing and such) to alter storage in a way that violates their integrity, and so to effectively enforce immutability of critical values.
In interesting case of true immutability in C/C++ is function values. There is simply no way to ask for changes in function code ("please nuke the third assignment in the function body for me"). Variables of function type do not exist, but function pointers are effectively just that, if we just think of making a function pointer point to a function as "storing the function, of the proper type, in the variable". Then all assignments are in fact realised as making the variable refer to different code, not of course as moving code into the memory originally holding other code (and programmers know this, which is why the variable is called a pointer). One could apply the same method to other types, implementing all assignments as rebinding of a reference. It is conceivable to have a non functional programming language in which all values are immutable, because all assignments are implemented this way. (There are efficiency issues to be dealt with, which might explain why I cannot think of examples of such languages, but they might well exist.)

"it is not the values (in the mathematical sense) themselves that change, just the question which values are contained in storage" - an interesting point which highlights one of the ways in which mathematicians tend to conceive of things differently. To the mathematician, numbers exist, always have, and always will. Whether they are contained in storage or not doesn't affect their existence. By this same logic, a string containing a work of Shakespeare existed before Shakespeare was even alive, and what Shakespeare did was merely to contain that work into storage. (1/2)

What is less clear in this conception is what space things exist in when they are not contained in storage, or how they come to storage from that other place. Computers have no imagination like the mathematician, so it is less clear what other space they are accessing when bringing things from this non-storage place into storage. (2/2)

@Steve This is getting into philosophical terrain, which is probably not the purpose of this question. But in mathematics "existence" has a different meaning than in the sciences, whether astronomy or history or whatever. A number like 46502 does not exist in a physical sense, and by choosing a much larger value it does not even exist in the looser sense of being an attribute (like the cardinal) of any entity or collection in reality. But in math one does not need such existence to state that 46502 is a member of the set of natural numbers, which does not exist in that manner either.

I think the implied philosophy is the difference. In a computer (a kind of machine), a "number" or a "value" is a physical state of a certain part of the storage hardware (a "field"). It's true to say these states represent something more meaningful to users, but that additional meaning of the states is in the head of the user, not inside the computer. So if you say that the "value is not changed" upon reassignment of a field, then if it isn't the state of the field being changed, then what is being changed instead? What else is there inside the computer besides the states? (1/2)

In my experience mathematicians tend to get a little bit sloppy with this and don't clearly differentiate between the machine and their minds. Programmers are better at this, because they are accustomed to writing software that multiple people use concurrently, and therefore the question of what is where and when, who knows what, and how information is mediated between people via the computer, becomes a core concern that it typically isn't for mathematicians who I think regard and use computers much more like personal calculators - and their conceptualisations adapt likewise. (2/2)

@Steve I think you are reading to much into what I said. Compare with the following fictive example: suppose my daughter currently measures 93cm and that subsequently she grows, as children are apt to do. Then nobody would say that 93cm is a mutable value, but instead that the (attribute) height of my daughter has changed, and is now given by a different value. In mathematics values are never mutable, for the simple reason that we like to say things that are always true, and that would not be possible if the values we are using are themselves changing. Of course we can still describe change.

I am reading a lot more into it than you intended, I hope you don't mind. I do follow your reasoning and I'm not complaining about it in its own terms, I'm simply observing that there are differences in how mathematicians tend to conceptualise things and use terminology. You are using the word "value" to refer to a number (in the sense of: a kind of mathematical object). Crucially, instances of the same number (or value) can be found in more than one place. A programmer meanwhile is more liable to use the word "value" to refer to the current contents of a storage location. (1/4)

I'd guess this leads to an understanding of assignment amongst mathematicians where there can be instantiation or de-instantiation of a number in a certain place, but not a modification of the number itself. It is therefore valid in this view to say the "value is not mutated". However, the programmer would equally say the "value is mutated", because for him the term "value" means "the current contents of a storage location", which is changed by the assignment. (2/4)

So far, there is no logical inconsistency, just conflated terminology. But now move on to asking "are these the same values?". The mathematician is liable to readily declare that the value 93 found in any two places "are the same". The experienced programmer is less likely to answer this definitively in the affirmative, unless either the two places in question are in fact the same place, or unless there is a common lineage of causation for the setting of the two places. YearOfBirth: 93 and HouseNumber: 93 are certainly "not the same values" to the programmer. (3/4)

In fact in programming, the numeric coincidence is only rarely important, as numbers (as well as codes and strings) are routinely employed for many incommensurate purposes, whereas the commonality (or not) of place or lineage is relevant extremely frequently. And this is why mathematicians, unless they are extremely skilled philosophers so as to cope with both areas, do not make good computer science educators, because the thinking (which they transmit to their students) originates from the typical concerns and context of mathematical analysis, rather than the context of data processing. (4/4)
